# cant install python package(gambit)

Tags: python, c++, windows, pip, package

I tried to install Gambit for python 3.6, but i faced this error :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I../.. -I../../library/include -I.. -IC:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include -IC:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpgambit/lib\libgambit.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\gambit/lib\libgambit.obj
libgambit.cpp
../../library/include\gambit/gambit.h(31): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2}

Answer (score 0):

Try to install microsoft visual studio 2019 build tools